# go through list of divs inserting a number

Tags: jquery

I want to add an index number to a set of divs I have, using JQuery :

```
<div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311"></div>
<div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311"></div>
<div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311"></div>
<div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311"></div>
```

so that it becomes this:

```
  <div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311">1</div>
    <div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311">2</div>
    <div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311">3</div>
    <div data-product-hotspot-pid="hbeu50220311">4</div>
```

These divs are also loaded in dynamically from a template from underscore, so is there a way to  like this:

```
$( ".swiper-wrapper" ).html(
_.template(template, {looks:looks})

);
```

so is there a way to wait until this has been done before we add in the index numbers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After appending the data, you can use:

```
 $(".swiper-wrapper div").each(function(i){
    $(this).text(i+1);
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HfL5G/)**